# I have tried to implement LIFO and recursion to reverse a char array, but it isn't working correctly

Tags: c

Why isn't this program code giving required output? I have tried to use recursion and LIFO concept to reverse a character array in this code.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 void reverse(char a[]);
 int main()
{
char a[] = "NAME";
printf("The original character string is: %s\n",a);
printf("The reversed string is:\n");
reverse(a);
system("pause");
}
void reverse(char a[])
{
static int i = 0;
int j = i;
while (a[i] == '\0')
{
    i++;
    reverse(a);
}
printf("%c", a[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to recurse, then don't use static variables. Recursion can be very simple. The following does what you want. Please study it carefully:

```
void reverse (char *s)
{
    if (*s!=0) {
        reverse (s+1);
        printf("%c", *s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all the condition should be:

```
 a[i]!='\0'
```

**and not**

```
 a[i] == '\0'
```

Secondly, it should be simple **if**, and not a **while**, loop, cause the recursion will take care of going through the char array.

Also why on earth you need **system()** function for this simple problem??

Thirdly, you dont need **j**, just post-decrement i while printing, which makes the correct code to be:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void reverse(char a[]);

int main()
{
    char a[] = "NAME";
    reverse(a); 
}

void reverse(char a[])
{
    static int i = 0;
    if(a[i]!='\0')
    {
        i++;
        reverse(a);
    }
    printf("%c",a[i--]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, in your code you don't need j variable.

Secondly, you have to use conditional statement **if** in the place of **while loop**. The loop will only iterate the recursive function again and again. The loop is very complex recursive function. For your understand take a pen and paper and draw the functionality of the recursive function very carefully!!!

Thirdly, condition will be

```
a[i]!='\0'
```

not

```
a[i]=='\0'
```

Fourthly,  for printing use decrement operator of **i**.
The reverse function should look like below:

```
void reverse(char a[])
{
    static int i = 0;

    if(a[i]!='\0')
    {
        i++;
        reverse(a);
    }
    printf("%c",a[i--]);
}
```

For reversing a String you can use the code below also,

```
#include<stdio.h>
void back_print(void)
{
    char ch;
    if((ch=getchar())!='\n')
        back_print();
    putchar(ch);
}

int main()
{
    printf("Enter a text line :");
    back_print();
}
```

The above code is called **backprint** code.

By using **LIFO** method(**Stack**) you can use the below code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100
int TOP=-1;
int stri[MAX_SIZE];
void push(char item)
{
    stri[++TOP]=item;
}

void pop()
{
    TOP--;
}

char top()
{
    return stri[TOP];
}

int main()
{
    char ch;
    printf("Enter the STRING: ");
    for(int i=0; i<MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        scanf("%c",&ch);

        if(ch=='\n')
            break;
        push(ch);
    }
    printf("After reverse the STRING is : ");
    for(int i=0; TOP>-1; i++)
    {
        printf("%c",top());
        pop();
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```